# Can't figure out how to download pip/ install libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've been trying to install the plotly library for a while. Whenever I try to run the commands, it doesn't work. I have Python (3.7.1) downloaded, and I know that because I open it and I can type in it. I try to do `$ pip install plotly`, as found in *[Getting Started with Plotly for Python](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/)*.

When I do that, it says invalid syntax. I don't really get how to download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py, which is the secure pip install file.

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

seems to work, but then when I try

```
python get-pip.py
```

It doesn't work again, because of an invalid syntax. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be great.

Comment: Are you sure? What does `python --version` print on your terminal?

Comment: In python 3.7 it says python isn't defined, in CMD it says 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. In Pycharm terminal, it says python isn't defined.

Comment: Are you running this in a REPL? Run from a terminal (bash/zsh) please

Comment: I tried it in bash, it says pip not found. I think I installed pip wrong, how do I download it from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Um no, all you have to do is just follow the instructions for installing by running whatever commands you need to in bash.

Comment: When I try to use pip in bash though, it says the command isn't found

Comment: If you have Python 3.7.1, pip is already installed according to the Python docs: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip

Comment: Why do you think you should be using pip to install pip?

Comment: How do I install it though? And I realize it should be installed, and I'm probably typing something wrong, I just don't know what it is

Comment: Do you know where Python is installed on your computer? I have Windows & for me it's in C:\Users\[my username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32.

Comment: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\

Comment: Awesome! From there, go to Lib and then site-packages & lemme know if you see a pip folder

Comment: What do you mean go to lib?

Comment: Inside my Python36-32 directory, I see another directory called Lib (right above another called libs) & inside that there's site-packages

Comment: Theres an ensurepip and a pipes.py

Comment: Navigate to your Python37 directory in bash & run `python -m ensurepip`. That should install pip automatically

Comment: How do I navigate it? Is that with CD? I tried it with CD and only could get it to C:\User\, also bash should be git bash right?

Comment: `cd` is what you would use. For me, both bash & cmd start in my username directory. All I have to type is `cd AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32`. If you're in C:\User\, you'd type `cd yourusername\AppData\...`. You can use either git bash or cmd for this.

Comment: EDIT: don't use bash with \, use / instead

Comment: Ok, I did that. Pip is definitely installed now, so what now?

Comment: As a sanity check, run `python --version` and `pip --version`. If they both work, run `pip install plotly`

Comment: `python --version` worked, `pip --version` said `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Did `python -m ensurepip` work properly?

Comment: Yes, I tried it again just in case and it says the requirement is satisfied

Comment: That is some weirdness. In any case, run `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` and `python get-pip.py` again. Now that you're in your Python installation directory, it should work

Comment: Wait, after "Requirement already satisfied", does it provide an install location for pip? If not, run the above commands

Comment: The first one seemed to work, the second one gave me this message ` The script wheel.exe is installed in `\C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

Comment: In that case, you'll need to add both your Python37 directory and the Scripts folder inside of it to PATH. Here's how: https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/

Comment: After that, you won't need to navigate to Python37 in order to run python or pip from the command line

Comment: I think it works, thanks so much for your help. If you want, type something as an answer and Ill check mark it!

Comment: Haha nah it's alright. I'm not here for the checkmarks. But for the sake of it, I can write out summary of what we did

Comment: 1. Make sure Python is added to PATH using [these steps](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/). You can check it by running `python --version` in the command line

2. Make sure pip is installed using `pip --version`. If not, run `python -m ensurepip`.

3. If that doesn't work for whatever reason, run `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` followed by `python get-pip.py`. That should allow you to run `pip install [stuff]` from anywhere

Comment: easy method: Uninstall python. Reinstall python and during installation, check the box that says “add python to your PATH” at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might be running the code with Python 2 instead of Python 3. Check the Python version with the following command.

```
python --version
```

Perhaps try and execute the program again by calling Python 3 directly

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: I tried all 3 option in CMD, python 3.7, and the pycharm IDE, it either says it's a syntax error or it is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were running on linux. Perhaps it might be that your environment path variables aren't set. Have you tried using the full path to execute the program? e.g. `c:\<your python directory path>\python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: This is probably a very beginner question I should know the answer to, but how do I tell what path it should be on?